# Pyspark code to download ARM template for azure data factoyr

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

Required code in pyspark to download ARM template in Azure data factory and store it in the dataframe

Comment: Why not store ADF in Git and get Pipeline definition from there? What benefit do you aim to get from getting the ARM template into Spark? (I presume into Databricks)

Comment: To have a validation check of linked services and activities in prod and pre-prod env.

Comment: Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-datafactory/azure.mgmt.datafactory.models?view=azure-python if there is a method you could use from python-sdk directly? To my knowledge there is no method to download ARM template at this point.

Comment: Yes, i did. But i didnt get any..